# Jquery, from keyword "this" to all td's in table

Tags: jquery, this

I have this:

```
$(document).on("click","#imgCancel",function(){
   $("#tbl_zones td").click(function(){
      editTables("#tbl_zones td",this)
   })
})
```

I'm trying to make the function more generic, so that it'll work on multiple tables. imgCancel is inside the table, and there will be an imgCancel in all the tables I'm making.

I've considered to replace the second line like this:

```
$(document).on("click","#imgCancel",function(){
   $(this).closest('table').find('td').click(function(){
      editTables("#tbl_zones td",this)
   })
})
```

It didn't work, though, and also I have no idea what to put as the first argument of editTables (which should refer to all td's in the current table).

Edit:
Modifying jknaack's jsfiddle, I ended up with this:

```
$(document).on("click","#imgCancel",function(){
    var tblID = $(this).closest('table').attr('id')
    $("#"+tblID+" td").click(function(){
        editTables("#"+tblID+" td",this)
    })
})
```

Comment: ID are unique. Means, in a page only one element can have ID `imgCancel`.

Comment: if you want it for more tables, add table class and name it imgCancel and in jquery use ".imgCancel"

Comment: Vega: I'm aware of that, there won't be more than one table at a time in the page.

Comment: Why are you putting a click handler inside a click handler?

Comment: Mark: Because I want the td elements of the table to become "clickable" after imgCancel is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a id must be unique in your document, use the class attribute instead.

> w3c The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the id attribute value must be unique within the HTML document).

- [w3c - ID Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp)

Comment: Maybe my question was a bit unclear. There will only be one table in the document at any given time. I need to know how I can go from imgCancel (this), which is inside a td in the table, to set a click event for all td's in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the inner id (assumption is it contains a td element)

```
$(document).on("click","#tbl_zones td", function(){
     editTables(this);
});
```

"this" in the function call would be the td element clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly, I think you can use some apporch where you pass the new selector  inside the clickable element as an data-attribute.

Its hard to know how your HTML will look like, so I just made an example. Of course you can customize the selector to only select inside the clicked element or at the closet.

JS code:

```
$(document).on("click",".actionbuttons",function(){
   var selectedElements = $($(this).data("selector"));
    selectedElements.css("background","#FF0000");
   $(selectedElements ).click(function(){
        $(this).css("background","#00FF00");
   })
})​
```

HTML Example:

```
<img class="actionbuttons" src="/" data-selector=".test1"/>
<div class="test1"></div>
<div class="test1"></div>
<div class="test1"></div>
<img class="actionbuttons" src="/" data-selector=".test2"/>

<div class="test2"></div>
<div class="test2"></div>
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ft7SB/